# socket.io SSL / HTTPS gives 404 Error on Client / Cannot connect to server

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, socket.io

my chat server was working fine on http but now im using letsencrypt and the client returns ERROR 404 in Chrome console when trying to recieve socket.io.js

In the following code samples I replaced my real domain with mydomain.de

Server is running without error:

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var mysql = require('mysql');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/chain.pem')
};

var serverPort = 8888;
var server = https.createServer(options, app);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('join room', function (data) {
       socket.join(data.room);
       console.log('user' + socket.id + ' joined ' + data.room);


    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('chat message', {is_sender: 0, msg: data.msg});
        socket.emit('chat message', {is_sender: 1, msg: data.msg});


    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


server.listen(serverPort, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + serverPort);
});
```

The Client side code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://mydomain.de:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('https://mydomain.de:8888');
</script>
```

Seems like the client cannot connect since the server in not logging any connections at all. What am I missing here? Trying to figure it out since hours and read a lot of examples or similar problems but cannot find the mistake I made.

Comment: can u give a working example. This info is like too less to conclude on anything

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And well this is pretty much all my code besides the rest of the client side which is just the basic html content. It cannot connect to the Server which I start with node. THe Client is NOT at the same domain like the server. I run the server on mydomain.de and the client on localhost on my computer.

Comment: I satrted the Server in DEBUG mode and it returns the following when i try to connect to the server: `express:application no routes defined on app +1s
  finalhandler default 404 +0ms`

Comment: I think express is not serving any routes which the socket could listen to. That could be a reason.